# Get the list of contact BUT "Other contacts"

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using this code to get the list of contacts on the phone.

```
String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { 
        ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID 
};

String order = "CASE WHEN " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, " 
        + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ", " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " COLLATE NOCASE";

String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";

Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);

if (cur.moveToFirst())
    do {
        Contact contact = new Contact(
                cur.getString(1), // Name
                cur.getString(3), // Email
                cur.getString(2)); // Photo

        if(contacts.indexOf(contact) == -1 && !contact.email.equals(Svc_Profil.getString(ProfilValues.email)))
            contacts.add(contact); 

    } while (cur.moveToNext());

cur.close();
```

This works very well. The problem is that this list contains all the contacts of the user, even the contacts in "Other Contacts" (which is a list automatically created and completed by Google when you send a mail to an unknown email address, even if you don't add this address to your contacts).

Does somebody know how to not get this "Other Contacts" in the result?

Thank you in advance.